# InputBox text not displayed in cell

Tags: excel, vba

There is something wrong with the following code. It correctly shows the InputBox when the user enters the values 9 or 10 in range `J1:J503`, but the InputBox output doesn't get shown in column L as I intended. Why?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim vrange As Range, cell As Range
  Dim TheAnswer$
  Set vrange = Range("J1:J503")
  If Intersect(vrange, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  For Each cell In Intersect(vrange, Target)
     If cell.Value = 9 Or cell.Value = 10 Then
        Target.Offset(0, 2).Select
        TheAnswer = InputBox("Please put comments", "Comments required for option 9 and 10")
     End If
  Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you didn't tell it to display anything in column L.

To do so, you can add this line of code just before `End If`:

```
Selection.Value = TheAnswer
```

Refactoring your code a little bit ([inline temp](http://refactoring.com/catalog/inlineTemp.html) and getting rid of `.Selection` which no one should ever use, in my opinion):

```
Dim vrange As Range, cell As Range
Set vrange = Range("J1:J503")
If Intersect(vrange, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
For Each cell In Intersect(vrange, Target)
    If cell.Value = 9 Or cell.Value = 10 Then
        With Target.Offset(0, 2)
            .Value = InputBox("Please put comments", "Comments required for option 9 and 10")
            .Select ' do you really need this? If not, get rid of it
        End With
    End If
Next cell
```